# Compile .dust files dynamically on client side

Tags: dust.js

I am trying to use client side dustJS templating in a Spring MVC framework. How do I compile all my .dust files before running the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile all the dust templates on build time (or before starting the app) and save them as JS. Then just load them when you need them, using `dust.loadSource` and once they are loaded you can render them.

Comment: Thanks! :) Now I am running a separate node server which auto detects changes to the dust files and i am including the js files in my main project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grunt for running build tasks, then you could compile your dust templates on the fly with the dust compiler plugin (below):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-dust-compiler